# Excel adding a sum only in specific instance

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a question. I have a sub total cell where I calculate total won income. Now, I have also have a column depicting won/lost/open. I would like for my column where the values for each entry gets counted (as well as the sub total cell)only if the one column says won

[image]

Comment: I am unsure what you want " I would like for my column where the values for each entry gets counted (as well as the sub total cell)only if the one column says won" does not provide a real issue, you want a column to do what? Is it an existing column or a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to

```
=SUMIF(Range, condition)
```

For further reference see the help page at: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

In your case

```
=SUMIF("G9:G12", "won")
```

asuming G9:G12 is the range of cells that you want to sum